# Time to [server] up a burnination

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I've come across the tag [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) a few times (I think each time, due to someone tagging [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) instead of [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)), however, upon looking at the tag, I don't really see how it's on-topic on Stack Overflow.

The usage guidance doesn't give any guidance:

> A server is a running instance of a software application capable of accepting requests from a client and giving responses accordingly.

Reading the wiki entry doesn't help either (it starts by repeating the "usage guidance"):

> A server is a running instance of an application (Software) capable of accepting requests from the client and giving responses accordingly.
>
> Servers can run on any computer including dedicated computers, which individually are also often referred to as "the server".
>
> In many cases, a computer can provide several services and have several servers running. The advantage of running servers on a dedicated computer is security. For this reason most of the servers are daemon processes and designed by the designers in such a way that they can be run on specific computer(s).
>
> There are various categories of servers. Please refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Servers_%28computing%29) Wikipedia page to learn more about the subcategories of servers.

Servers aren't really a topic that is on-topic for Stack Overflow; more likely if you are asking about a server then you want [Super User](//superuser.com) or [Server Fault](//serverfault.com) (though others could be relevant). It's very unlikely that the process is running on a server is relevant.

To answer the burnination request questions:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
   Not really; that the user is asking about a server doesn't really matter from a programming sense. I suppose it's not unambiguous as to what it's about, the physical machine, but I fail to see how that is relevant. The usage "guidance" appears to suggest that the "server" is the application, rather than the hardware, however, "server" could be interpreted as either.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   No, servers themselves aren't on topic; for support on those then a different site in the community is likely more relevant (such as the previously mentioned [Server Fault](//serverfault.com)).
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   No, as mentioned that the code is running on a server, rather than a PC, is irrelevant.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   *Probably*, but also as I often see if used incorrectly, then no. The combination of the tags [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) should not mean the question is about the RDBMS product SQL Server; that's what the tag [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) is for.

<sub>Suggestions for punny names are welcome.</sub>

Comment: "Disconnect the [server]"? "Let's light this [server] on fire"?

Comment: "Let the [server] suffer the DDOS"?

Comment: It sounds a lot like you're taking the possible secondary meaning of "server" from the tag (a system that happens to be configured to run server software for multiple clients), instead of the primary meaning (a piece of software that takes requests from and returns responses to client software, e.g. a http server, ftp server, COM server, etc). The tag is ambiguous imo, but not off-topic at all.

Comment: "Time to [server] up a burnination"?

Comment: At least at first glance, I don't see how [server] is any better than [computer] would be; it doesn't really seem to add any useful information to a question's context. If something specific is happening on a server, we can have a tag for _that thing_ (e.g. like [server-side-rendering]), but you can't really be an expert in "server" by itself... it's just not specific.

Comment: "sever the connection to [server]". Hm. See I really liked the sever/server bit, but I can't really make it snappy.

Comment: Heat up the burninate la[ser ver]y soon.

Comment: At 25071 questions (and counting, as of 39 minutes ago) it seems the effort to burninate could be a lot more than the positive effect of removing it.

Comment: To @Nick's point, maybe this is one that would be good to blocklist to prevent _more_ uses of this bad tag, encourage its removal from existing questions, etc.

Answer (score -7):

> Servers aren't really a topic that is on-topic for Stack Overflow;

Programming a server is certainly on-topic. Sounds a tad bit broad at first sight, but there are many ways to focus questions about this.

> It's very unlikely that the process is running on a server is relevant.

Certainly, unless the process "is" the server. [Here's a question about server development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76920662/7395227), for instance.

Comment: i mean... from the point of view of "programming" the server is just code, this tag is more or less a meta tag.

Comment: "many ways to focus questions about this" ...by adding the relevant tags, in which case the tag [tag:server] has no use.

Comment: `server` is too broad. A `server` of what?

Comment: `server`, `software`, `programming` or similar tags, does not add much value on SO.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the objection, server-side programming in the client-server paradigm is distinct from client-side programming. Bugs in, for example, sockets API code can be very different from client-side socket API code. Also, concepts like concurrency and the associated APIs are often critical in server-side programming but not so much in client-side code.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk then it should be called server-side-programming. Server is woefully ambiguous.

Comment: The linked question is actually about why *threads* cannot be cancelled. Tacking on "server" as the scope and thus limiting it incorrect makes the question *worse*, I would say. This seems rather like an example of why a `server` tag doesn't work well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi as the OP of that question, I originally did not know that the scope of my question was "threads" nor did I know that was specifically the issue with the functionality I referred to. In hindsight, sure, I'm not opposed to retagging it as being about threads now, but I can't imagine myself using that tag originally. So, given that my question was about what looked to me like a standard for any known server in a server-client relationship, the server tag seemed sensible.